# What reasons can cause a MongoDB update operation to fail?

Tags: mongodb, transactions

I am implementing some transactions using MongoDB. Since I have to implement my own rollback (and since the rollback could possibly fail), I would like to know what type of errors could prevent an update operation to succeed.

Here are the reasons I expect to meet:

1. **Network issues** (in which case we need to retry later),
2. **The query didn't find the object I want to update** (in which case the rollback should just ignore the update and continue with the other steps)

Is there any other reason that could prevent an update operation to succeed?

**UPDATE:**
This question is about knowing the different types of possible failure, so that the application's code can react to them accordingly.

Comment: Yes. Duplicating some value with unique index will cause update to fail.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny if write simple 'update({1:2, 3:4})' it will not cause the problem because `ObjectID()` will be saved during `insert` query

Comment: If you're needing transactions and trying to add your own rollback, you're doing it wrong. Either your document structure could be improved (so you won't need transactions any more) or your problem is not suited for MongoDB / non-transactional databases. Transactions and error handling are complicated, relational databases spent years on getting it right; don't try to roll your own. However, you might be able to use optimistic locking for your problem - this is supported by some drivers. You might want to give it a look.

Comment: You could run out of space, the system could crash (shut off) in the middle of your update.

Comment: @xeraa: you were totally right, an SQL-based db would have been way better. MongoDB was kind of pushed on me because it was said to be scalable and my boss had a lot of ambition for his business. I would say 'no' if it was to be done again today.